# Bitmap byte manipulation in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, png, transparency, gif

Struggling with manipulating the underlying bytes of a Bitmap object to remove the transparency of an image.
I have a static remove transparency method, that takes a Bitmap object, relevent code: http://pastebin.com/ZjjPSdx8

Now when I call this with a Bitmap object based on a File, the bitmap isn't mutated. If I understand correctly this is because as it's based on a File as per http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814675

So created a method to copy the bitmap:
http://pastebin.com/9rXRJ6cx

```
private Bitmap LoadBmp(string name)
    {
        Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string loc = Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location);
        string path = Path.Combine(loc, "Images\\" + name);
        Bitmap notsafe = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);
        return ImageProcessor.SafeBitmap(notsafe);
...
```

All fine and dandy. Works well with PNGs, however not with GIFs. They come out horribly 
distorted.

Tried an alternate method writing the file to a byte array, and then basing the bitmap on that:

```
        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int c;
        byte[] imgArr;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                while ((c = fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0)
                    ms.Write(b, 0, c);
                imgArr = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(imgArr));
```

This doesn't distort the gif's. however my remove transparency method no longer works on the PNGs!
Clearly I'm doing something wrong, hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Not related directly to your question but if there's a wonderful `ReadAllBytes()` method on the `File` object, `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

You can solve your immutable bitmap problem when loading from a file as such:

`var bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile("C:\bmp.bmp"))`

That prevents you from having to do any Marshal.Copy (which are slow), it also solves your problem with GIFs getting mutilated and distorted.  The internal .NET code which does this, if you're interested is the following:

```
 g = Graphics.FromImage(this);
 g.Clear(Color.Transparent); 
 g.DrawImage(original, 0, 0, width, height);
```

so it is essentially the code I gave you below, for solving your transparency problem, which didn't meet your speed needs.

However, if you you can do the load and copy at the same time via g.FromImage, I got speeds of `(5.6 seconds g.FromImage vs 6.4 seconds yours with 1000 gifs @ 543x341)`

In theory you can make yours faster, if you combine the copying and removing transparency into the same function.  If you load a GIF without rewriting the image, it will be in a different pixel format, in fact, `8bppindexed`, which means your function won't work as is.  Either way, the solution above will solve the issue when using your CheckIfTransparent function, and the solution below (I had to edit a little of it) will do it faster.  I may spend some time looking to that if I do.  I find the problem interesting.

I did notice that your algo to remove the alpha isn't completely accurate.  I'm not sure where exactly, but your algo looks wrong when used with transparent gradients.  The one using straight GDI looks as expected.  I would make sure you're converting the colors correctly.

---

If you just want to remove the transparency on a png or a gif, doing all this `Marshal.Copy` and unsafe code, why not just create a new Bitmap, draw the background white, and then overlay the exiting png/gif on it?  Seems like less complicated code.

EDIT:  Something like this:

```
    public static Bitmap ManagedSafeBitmap(string file)
    {
        using (var img = Image.FromFile(file))
        {
            var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);
            bmp.SetResolution(img.HorizontalResolution, img.VerticalResolution);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.White);
                g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
            }

            return bmp;
        }
    }
```

That will give you a new image with a white background, and put the source image on top of that, effectively changing all transparent pixels to `Color.White` or whatever color you want to pass `g.Clear()`

Comment: Great job of thinking about the bigger picture!

Comment: Yeah, did this originally but wanted to squeeze abit more speed out of it.. The managed method is about 50% slower than the combination of MakeSafe and CleanTransparent. Without the makesafe (though admittedly it doesn't work without that..) it's 300% slower.
I'll be processing ALOT of images so that speed difference is important... (100's of millions).

Comment: Thanks! Did some speed tests of my own, and the combined load and transparent (managed vs unmanaged) I'm getting speeds of 5.1 vs 5.3 p/1000. The advantage however is that the unmanaged method is faster when the image doesn't have transparency (optionally remove transparency only for images that support it) - A large amount of our images will be jpg's too..
Regardless spent too much time on this, so for now I'm going with your method - deadlines and all...
However still very interested on why the image gets distorted and I'd love to get the orig method to work.. If any can help :)

Comment: I think the image is getting distorted during the copy, not the transparency change.  The GIF loaded is loaded with an indexed pallete, and I think the Marshal.Copy is copying the existing data into a different pixelformat.  The Bitmap.LockBits expects you to know the PixelFormat, and I think it was being set to 32bitArgb when it should be 8bppindexed.  Of course, you can't do a Marshal.Copy then and expect proper results, as you'd have to transform each pixel, which is generally a lossy conversion, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with the [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) class. I heard that has been created just for pixel manipulation using managed code.